# How do I change the date format of a single result?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a view that gives me a list of nodes titles and when it was last updated.

I want to display the changed date with only time if it is today, otherwise I just want the date, e.g. 17.00 or 15 may 2016.

If I look at the result in views_pre_render it has a node_changed timestamp. It uses the date format set in the view. How do I change the format just for the first result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a template file and in that you can have and the template files you can get that in

[image]

```
if($view->row_index == 1){
   // do your stuff
}
```

and put your own condition